# Navigation Drawer freezing when adding Gridview to the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview, android-navigation

I am using a navigation drawer and a grid view on the same activity but once i did that, i am not able to scroll or click anything on the activity. Moreover, navigation drawer also refuses to open or respond to touch. I have checked my code at least 3 times now but still i cant figure out why its not working.

Activity code:

```
package com.project.iandwe;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.project.iandwe.Adaptor.EventAdapter;
import com.project.iandwe.Adaptor.NavigationDrawerListAdapter;
import com.project.iandwe.Fragments.DetailedEvent;
import com.project.iandwe.Menu.*;
import com.project.iandwe.Navigation.NavigationDrawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by NathanDrake on 5/10/2014.
 */
public class HomePage extends FragmentActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    //public static final int ADD_EVENT_REQUEST =1;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence drawerTitle;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence title;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavigationDrawer> navigationDrawers;
    private NavigationDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    //private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
        actionBar.show();

        //Initialize grid view for home page for displaying events
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewCalendar);
        gridView.setAdapter(new EventAdapter(this));
        //for Slider menu
        title = drawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        navigationDrawers = new ArrayList<NavigationDrawer>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navigationDrawers.add(new NavigationDrawer(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // View Contacts
        navigationDrawers.add(new NavigationDrawer(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // View Groups
        navigationDrawers.add(new NavigationDrawer(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // View Invites
        navigationDrawers.add(new NavigationDrawer(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // View Settings
        navigationDrawers.add(new NavigationDrawer(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Log Off
        navigationDrawers.add(new NavigationDrawer(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navigationDrawers);
        drawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.
                ic_drawer,    //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // navigation drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name
        ) { // navigation drawer close - description for accessibility
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(title);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerListView);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_add).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedEvent.class);
        intent.putExtra("Eventid","");
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */

    private  class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ContactsFragments();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new GroupFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new InvitesFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new LogOffFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();;
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerListView.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        this.title = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(this.title);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_event_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddEvent.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

My xml code for the same activity looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>


        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#FFCC00"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <GridView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridViewCalendar"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:columnWidth="174dp"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clipChildren="true"

            />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I checked the steps from this page : [creating a navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) The thing is if i remove the drawer or the grid view, everything works fine. I tried invalidating cache and restart (using IntelliJ) but still no luck. Checked other questions on SO but till now no luck in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the onclick listener of the gridview inside the gridview adaptor class itself and then things started working.. not sure why this happened.